# Provider org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.DefaultSource could not be instantiated

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a simple spark job that is reading data from Hive and some from db2, does some calculations and puts the results in db2. In the line of code where I try to read data from db2, I see the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.DefaultSource could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:533)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
at com.ibm.sifs.trade.framework.persistence.TradePersistence.persistTradeSummary(TradePersistence.java:697)
at com.ibm.sifs.trade.summaries.IntraDaySummary.main(IntraDaySummary.java:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
  org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/DefaultSource.createRelation(Lorg/apache/
  spark/sql/SQLContext; 
  [Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/collection/immutable
  /Map;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelation; @35: areturn
Reason:
Type 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/OrcRelation' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/spark/sql/sources/HadoopFsRelation' (from method signature)
Current Frame:
bci: @35
flags: { }
locals: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/DefaultSource', 'org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext', '[Ljava/lang/String;', 'scala/Option', 'scala/Option', 'scala/collection/immutable/Map' }
stack: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/hive/orc/OrcRelation' }
  Bytecode:
0x0000000: b200 1c2b c100 1ebb 000e 592a b700 22b6
0x0000010: 0026 bb00 2859 2c2d b200 2d19 0419 052b
0x0000020: b700 30b0                              

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
... 27 more
```

These are the jars in my spark-submit command :

```
--files /etc/spark2/2.6.4.0-91/0/hive-site.xml,/etc/spark2/2.6.4.0-91/0/hbase-site.xml --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hbase/lib/hbase-server.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hbase/lib/hbase-client.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hbase/lib/hbase-common.jar --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/spark2/2.6.4.0-91/0/log4j.properties" --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/sifsuser/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hive/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hbase/lib/*"
```

Comment: The issue was due to multiple versions of Spark in the environment. Fixed it by setting the SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 in the linux environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to spark version mismatch. Check if you have same version of spark in both your local and also in your project bundle. 
I ran into this issue when I had spark 2.2 at my mac and 2.4 at my maven project. When I matched the version, everything worked fine.